# scrapy, I am trying to remove empty lines that are extracted to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, blank-line

I am extracting data from one page. I have to go deeper, of course, but I am still stuck on that first page. This is my code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from street.items import HstreetItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "go-h"
allowed_domains = ["http://somedomain.com"]
start_urls = ["http://somedomain.com"]

def parse(self,response):
    #response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace('\n', '')) # doesn't work
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    details = hxs.select('//tr')
    items = []
    #n = 0
    for detail in details:
        item = HondastreetItem()
        item['url'] = "".join(detail.select('td[@class="Model_LineModel_odd"]/a/@href | td[@class="Model_LineModel_even"]/a/@href').extract()).strip()
        item['model'] = "".join(detail.select('td[@class="Model_LineModel_odd"]/a/text() | td[@class="Model_LineModel_even"]/a/text()').extract())
        item['year'] = "".join(detail.select('td[@class="Model_LineYear_odd"]/text() | td[@class="Model_LineYear_even"]/text()').extract())            
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

The code works fine and it extracts data through my pipeline into a CSV file like it should:

```
cell 1 | cell2 | cell3
url    | model | year
 .
 .
 .
```

The problem is that I have a lot of empty lines in my csv file. At the beginning 17 lines and then empty lines in between filled lines of my CSV file. I think that a few tables in front of the crawled table and some rows inside the crawled table that I don't need (like category names) are causing this.
I am stuck with this last 24 hours :( I have been trying all the solutions that I found via similar questions but nothing worked for me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are not showing your csv writing code. Have you tried to [debug your code](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/)? You should be able to tell with certainty where the empty lines are coming from. Also, if we can't see the html table structure, we can't really tell if the problem is there. You should at least post example html

Comment: If you can provide actual URLs, then we'll be able to test your code more thoroughly. :)

Comment: Csv writing code was not really important, I used piplines.py for that. Its probably a place were you can prevent empty lines to be written as well but then I just wanted to clean up everything before it gets written to csv. I mentioned in my question that probably <tr> table rows in same table were causing this, check question...haraprasadj simple answer proves that everything was clear in my question. Anyway thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite new to Python and landed here trying to understand scrapy.

From what I understand you must be appending empty lines. So you might try to check if 'item' is not empty before the append statement, e.g.,

```
if not (item['url'] == "" and item['model'] == "" and item['year'] == ""):
    items.append(item)
```

Please ignore if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: good suggestion. You can simplify the condition to be just `ìf item['url'] or item['model'] or item['year']` (empty strings evaluate to false in python)

Comment: Glad to help :) you can also try `if any(map(item.get, ('url','model','year')))`, or even simply `if any(item.values())`, if there's nothing else on item. There's too many possible ways to do this

Comment: The simplicity of logic! And I was after some functions :)